# Back arrow - error: cannot find symbol class MenuItem

Tags: android, optionmenu

I was trying to intent The `getSupportActionBar()` to the previous page.
While creating a back arrow to `toolbar` , I am getting an error for the second method says **`error: cannot find symbol class MenuItem`**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override // This method creates the error
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This to get click event of back arraow

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
           // perform Your action here
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and in your manifest file  add parent activity to your activity like this

```
    <activity
        android:name=".yourActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".ParentActivityname"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

**MainActivity.java**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);


   }

    @Override // This method creates the error
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       switch(item.getItemId()) {
           case android.R.id.home:
              startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
             return true;
        }
        return false;

     }
```

Add the meta-data tag in your AndroidManifest.xml inside  tag like this

```
       <activity
        android:name=".StartActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="your package name.MainActivity">

         <meta-data
           android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
           android:value="your package name.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

**Note: Change "your package name" to your project package name**

Answer (score 0):

Ratilal Chopda already posted the right answer, here is only the solution in pretty code

```
public class ServicesViewActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // etc...
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

The function `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this)` requires you to define the parent activity in the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
  <activity android:name="com.example.ServicesViewActivity" >
            <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.ParentActivity" />
    </activity>
```

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back

Comment: thanks if you think my ans is correct than please up vote my ans

Answer (score 0):

You could also check if menu item was imported properly
that was my own experience the class wasn't imported hence it couldn't find the `MenuItem`